# hibernate validation not working while one-to-one mapping in between two entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, one-to-one

During form submission, if there is any validation error then form shows the errors messages under the fields. But the actual problem is in another place. I have two entities **User** and **UserDetails**. These entities are mapped with each other by bidirectional one-to-one mapping. Validation is working only with the **User** entity fields but not with the **UserDetails** entity.

**Spring - 5.0.2**`
**Hibernate - 5.2.10**

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotEmpty(message="{common.error.msg}")
private String first_name;

@NotEmpty(message="{common.error.msg}")
private String last_name;

@NotEmpty(message="{common.error.msg}")
private String status;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private UserDetails userDetails;

//Getter and setter methods
}
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int user_id;

@NotEmpty(message="{common.error.msg}")
private String address;

@NotEmpty(message="{common.error.msg}")
private String mobile;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private User user;

//Getter and setter methods
}
```

Get and Post methods in the controller class

```
@GetMapping(value="/create")
public String loadUserForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", new User());
    return "backend/oms/user/form";  //JSP
}

@PostMapping(value="/create")
public String Save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command") User user, BindingResult br, Model model, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    if(br.hasErrors()) {
        return "backend/oms/user/form"; //JSP
    } else {
        try {
            int id = userService.save(user);
            if(id > 0) {
                ra.addFlashAttribute("flash_msg", "ok|User added!");
                return "redirect:/oms/user/edit/"+id;
            } else {
                return "backend/oms/user/create"; //JSP
            }
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            model.addAttribute("err", "Something wrong! Please try again.");
            return "backend/oms/user/form"; //JSP
        }
    }
}
```

**messages.properties**

```
common.error.msg=This field is required!
```

**form.jsp**

```
<form:form action="/oms/user/create" method="post" modelAttribute="command">
     <label>First Name</label>
     <form:input path="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
     <form:errors cssClass="error" path="first_name" />

     <label>Last Name</label>
     <form:input path="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />
     <form:errors cssClass="error" path="last_name" />

     <label>Mobile</label>
     <form:input path="userDetails.mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" value="" />
     <form:errors cssClass="error" path="userDetails.mobile" />

     <label>Address</label>
     <form:textarea path="UserDetails.address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" value="" />
    <form:errors cssClass="error" path="userDetails.address" />

    <label>Status</label>
    <form:select class="form-control" path="status">
       <option value="">Choose...</option>
       <option value="E">Enable</option>
       <option value="D">Disable</option>
    </form:select>
    <form:errors path="status" cssClass="error"/>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />

</form>
```

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyCWJ.jpg)
As you can see the image only fields from the User entity is validating but fields those are from the UserDetails are not validating. Please help.

Comment: It is solved now by me. @Valid annotation solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now. @Valid annotation solved my problem. I need to put @Valid annotation before the entity variable declaration like below --

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="majorHead", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Valid
private List<MinorHead> minorHead = new ArrayList<MinorHead>();
```

Comment: no, it does not work!